# How can I change the Total of price existing in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

How Can I change the Total price of the cart using hook.
I have tried many hooks without result.
i'm probably arrived to find the result .

This is what I have tried.

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wh_getCartItemBeforePayment', 10);

function wh_getCartItemBeforePayment(){
if($_POST['percent']){
            if($_POST['percent']==1){

                /*WC()->cart->total*0.25;

                WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
                woocommerce_cart_totals();*/
                /*

                add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );
                function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
                    global $woocommerce;

                    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
                    return;

                    $percentage = 0.01;
                    $surcharge = ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total + $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total ) * $percentage;    
                    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Surcharge', $surcharge, true, '' );

                }

                throw new Exception( __( WC()->cart->total ) );*/

                    //$items = WC()->cart->get_cart();

                    $cupom_value=-1;
                        foreach ($items as $item => $values)
                        {

                            $_product = $values['data']->post;
                            $product_title = $_product->post_title;
                            $qty = $values['quantity'];
                            $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'], '_price', true);


                            $post_id = $value['product_id'];
                            $regular_price = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', true);
                            $sale_price = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price', true);
                            $cupom_value = ($regular_price - $sale_price) *0.25;
                            $price = $cupom_value;
                            $value['data']->price = $price;



                        }
                        //$price=3*0.25;
                        wc_add_notice($cupom_value, 'error' );
            }}}
```

Comment: This question is not clear… first which version of WooCommerce are you using? What is `$_POST['percent']`? Is this a custom checkout field? … Too many questions, as you don't really explain what are you are trying to do, how and where… So please *edit your question* to make it clear as we can't guess and we aren't a Wizard.

Comment: I use  WooCommerce 2.6.14 .

$_POST['percent']  its my own input that i have created in chekout page i created link this  :
<input type="radio" name="percent" value=1>25%
<input type="radio" name="percent" value=2>100%  ..
if a client choose 25%  the total of the price has to decrease up to 25%

Comment: i want to decrease  the total before the page payement show up

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'action_cart_calculate_totals', 10, 1 );

function action_cart_calculate_totals( $cart_object ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( !WC()->cart->is_empty() ):

        $cart_object->cart_contents_total += 10; // add 10 to cart total

    endif;
}
```